# Elastic Search total index size

Tags: elasticsearch, size, elasticsearch-indices

I am trying to get the actual size of index (not the store) in elasticsearch. I used the indices API to get the stats.

```
GET doc/_stats
```

Is "indexing"-"index_total" actual index size?

```
"total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 1000000,
        "deleted": 0
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 118078896
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 1000000,
        "index_time_in_millis": 30985,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get the all index sizes using this command, showing separately

```
curl '192.168.x.x:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```